Exercise 14.6.1 of 'The probabilistic methods'
Here is the problem:
Let $A$ be a set of $n$ points in the plane, and let $T$ be the set of all intersections
of $A$ with an open triangle in the plane. Prove that the discrepancy of $T$ does
not exceed $n^{1/4+o(1)}.$
I am asking for the meaning of "the set of all intersections
of $A$ with an open triangle." My understanding is that: you draw an open triangle (only the interior of a triangle?) and it intersects $A$ at a subset $B\subset A$. And $T$ it the collection of all such possible $B$. Is it correct?

Yes,  I'd think an open triangle means the interior of a triangle.  For the rest,  I believe they mean for you to consider all such triangles and form all possible intersections.  So the empty set and the full set are in,  as is every singleton and so on.

Not entirely sure of that.

I would agree with your interpretation, Zeta
